# How to see the weights of each layer of LSTM model?

Tags: python, lstm

I have the following LSTM model which I trained and saved its weights into hdf5 file.
How can I load/print/see the weights of each layer?

```
# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]),return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(256))#change to 256
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')


### Generating text ###
# load the network weights
weightsfile = "C:\\Users\\...\\weights-improvement.hdf5"
model.load_weights(weightsfile)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: Pytorch? Or Keras? If Pytorch: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/what_is_state_dict.html

Answer (score 0):

In pytorch you can loop over the models parameters like this:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    print(type(param), param.size())

# <class 'torch.Tensor'> (20L,)
# <class 'torch.Tensor'> (20L, 1L, 5L, 5L)
```

From there you can print out the layers etc

In tensorflow you can view the layers with: `print(model.trainable_variables)`

and this will show you something that looks like this:

```
    [<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 32) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 
'dense/kernel:0' shape=(6272, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' 
shape=(32,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(32, 10) 
dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>]
```

You can then look for a specific weights by name like this:

```
var = [v for v in model.trainable_variables() if v.name == 'conv2d/bias:0'][0]
```